# KDE flying bits animation - how do I stop this annoyance?

Tags: kde

When I close a dialog box, or interact with some UI controls, I get a flying rectangles animation where they start small near the site of my mouse cursor, then fly out toward the edge of the desktop, getting larger as they appear to come at me.

I just want to turn it off, and live the rest of my life in quiet contemplation.  Can you help?  Please do!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a feature that you accidentally activated or if you are experiencing a bug. If it is an animation, you should be able to disable it via *Desktop Effects* in *System Settings*.

[image]

I couldn't reproduce what you described, as I currently only have a virtual machine at hand that doesn't seem to support hardware compositing.

Answer (score 1):

I dumped LightDM and went back to KDM (the change to LightDM happened when I upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04).  Gone are the flying bits!

Comment: Interesting, so you were able to solve your problem yourself. However we don't know what it really was.